# How to terminate a loop when a letter entered in C?

Tags: c

In my task I need to use a loop and get an input between 1-5, if i get any other input i need to keep iterating until i get 1-5.

Could you please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Part of my code:

```
int rateSelected, weeklyHours;

    printf("Enter the number corresponding to the desired pay rate or action:\n");
    printf("1) %.2lf$/hr                               2) %.2lf$/hr\n", RATE1, RATE2);
    printf("3) %.2lf$/hr                              4) %.2lf$/hr\n", RATE3, RATE4);
    printf("5) Quit\n");

    while ((scanf("%d", &rateSelected)) != EOF && rateSelected != 5)
    {
        if (rateSelected > 5 || isalpha(rateSelected) ==1){
            printf("please enter a number between 1-5:\n");
        continue;
        }

        printf("Now enter your weekly hours:\n");
        scanf("%d", &weeklyHours);
        ChoosePayRate(rateSelected, weeklyHours);
    }
```

tnx

Comment: If the input has to be 'between 1-5' you should also check for 'rateSelected < 1' in your condition.

Comment: If someone entered a letter, `scanf("%d", &rateSelected)` will fail, return 0 (which is `!=EOF`) _and leave the offending input in the buffer_ for the next `scanf`, infinite loop (unless `rateSelected` happened to have the value 5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your use of `%d` format specifier. When letters are entered instead of digits, `scanf` returns zero to indicate that nothing is read. If you would like to allow entering letters along with digits, you should either add a read of a string when `scanf` returns zero, or always read into a string buffer, and then use `sscanf` or `atoi` to convert the string to integer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `isalpha(rateSelected)`.

`isalpha()` checks if the value passed as parameter is an alphanumeric character - but you are passing the `int` value which you have just read.

However, this is still not sufficient - you would need to catch the return value from `scanf()` to check if `scanf()` has actually read an `int`. But if no int was entered, the characters are not discarded so that the next scanf() will again try to convert them, which leads to an endless loop.
Better use the solution provided by @dasblinkenlight.

Answer (score 0):

`isalpha(rateselected)` will never be true because you are storing an int in `rateselected`.
`scanf("%d",rateselected)` allready takes care of catching character input, and returns 0 if that is the case.  So you should change the `isalpha` test to a `rateselected == 0` test.

Also, scanf will never return EOF. It will return 0, and then you need to test `feof(stdin)` to see if you really hit the end of input. (which would correspond to a `ctrl-Z` for keyboard input).

Comment: Not exactly. `isalpha()`, in fact, works with `int`. It's just that `scanf()`, encountering the `%d` format specifier, doesn't convert if the input is not an integer.

Comment: right.  `isalpha()` tests that the input value corresponds to an ascii  character.  but scanf(%d) would not produce an ascii value when encountering a character, it would reject it.

Answer (score 0):

You better use `fgets()` and `strtol()` for this. Scanf and the line-buffering of `stdio` is not very helpful together...

```
char line[LINE_MAX];
do {
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
} while(!isdigit(line[0]));
int choice = strtol(line, NULL, 10);
```

Comment: Thank you buddy. Unfortunately i didnt get to fgets in the book yet, to the exercise is required using scanf..@H2CO3

Comment: @user1959174 That's not something reasonable of a complaint. You should generally avoid `scanf()`. If you don't know precisely what it does, look up its documentation on opengroups.org.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
int e;
while ((e = scanf("%d", &rateSelected)) != EOF)
{
    scanf("%*[^\n]"); // this clean your input buffer
    if (e==0 || rateSelected>5 || rateSelected<1) {
        printf("please enter a number between 1-5:\n");
        continue;
    }
```

instead of

```
    while ((scanf("%d", &rateSelected)) != EOF && rateSelected != 5)
    {
        if (rateSelected > 5 || isalpha(rateSelected) ==1){
            printf("please enter a number between 1-5:\n");
        continue;
        }
```

Comment: i tried to replace it but when i enter a letter i get "please enter a number between 1-5" in a loop..@MohamedKALLEL

Comment: See the comment from @DanielFischer

Comment: @user1959174 I updated the code Just add `scanf("%*[^\n]");` to clean your buffer after each `scanf("%d");`